# Emission Problems in Blender Render

Tags: materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, light, text-object

So I'm trying to make an intro for my youtube channel, and I made a shockwave effect for the background. It looks great, and as expected, my username without a material is pitch black in the render since it has no emissions on the material. But, when I do use even a fraction of an emission to help the colors pop out, the whole thing is blindingly bright. It doesn't even have to be an emission material! A lamp shining on the object is enough to recreate the same problem.

[image]

As you can see, the object is too bright, but it also doesn't show the true colors. I'm using a blue material and, get this, an orange material. I'm assuming the shockwave is providing light that is reflecting its own hue on the text. How do I make the true colors of my text pop out? (I also hope to give it some reflective lighting effects with a point lamp, but thats for another time.)

Comment: Could you upload your blend file. I would have a better idea why it would be doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't yet comment, I have to reply as an "awnser."

You could maybe try rendering the username on a different scene with less light sources.